# Android: simplest way for an Application to "remember" a single piece of information?

Tags: android

I have an android application that needs to store a single piece of information between runs: a 4 digit int. This info should not be discarded.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences:

```
static final String PREFS_MY_KEY = "insert your key name here";
```

Write (ctx is a Context, e.g. the activity):

```
final SharedPreferences prefs =  ctx.getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
final Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt(PREFS_MY_KEY, yourInteger);
editor.commit();
```

Read:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs =  ctx.getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.getInt(PREFS_MY_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

use SharedPreferences. Reference Link is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use SharedPreferences

It saves a value in the preferences of the android application and it is the best way to store a small amount of information

Also read: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

if you need to store a lot of information use SqlLite

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SharedPreferences` - [example](http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/sharedPreferencesTutorial.html)